# Cannot print the first 5 rows using df.head(5)

Tags: python

Complete noob here. I've been trying the following instructions to access a data set on Kaggle and to read the first 5 rows.

https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-with-python-c9ab422ec29c

I'm using spyder and when I run the following code, I only obtain a runfile wdir= comment in the console

Following is the Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('weight-height.csv')
df.head(5)
```

Output:
[Code and Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phcR9.png)

Comment: FYI, it's better to post formatted code blocks and messages here vs a screen shot in case the linked image(s) change or get removed from the other website. [See how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The medium post is probably using [jupyter notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) which will take the last line and put it as formatted output in a cell below it without a `print`. In a regular python script / idle or other IDEs, you need to actually use the `print` function to print to the terminal/console.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('weight-height.csv')
print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you.